# How do I resolve this " No such property [target] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" and "No output stream or file set for the appender named" error?

Tags: eclipse, log4j, slf4j

I managed to get log4J with ConsoleAppender to work in Eclipse, but when I change the appender to be FileAppender  then I get these red error messages coming out(even though I altered the properties file as directed by this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6NhHDUCNQY)) :

```
log4j:WARN No such property [target] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [file].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [file].
```

Here is a pic[image]

Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, `FileAppender` has a `File` option, not a `Target` option.

Comment: Hmm, so I'm setting it up as if it is a Target ? I'll go back & study up on this, I'm not sure I get the difference

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your configuration to something like this:

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=testlog.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was:

```
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
```

I removed that properties of my 'log4j.properties' and resolved it.

```
log4j.appender.logFile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.DatePattern=_yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logFile.File=output.log
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Yes, a DailyRollingFileAppender rolls over "Daily".  A RollingFileAppender rolls over based on the MaxFileSize property value.  hth, adym